# If I add both selection and drag and drop to an ExtJS grid, how can I unselect on drag?

Tags: extjs

When I make a grid like this:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [
            { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
            { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
            { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        selModel: {
            injectCheckbox: 1,
            mode: 'SIMPLE'
        },
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: [
                { ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop' }
            ]
        },
    })
```

I don't want the checkboxes checked when dragging because:

1. I only want to drag one item at a time,
2. I want to be able to multiselect for other actions.

I can add a listener to deselectAll after the drop but:

1. This leaves the item selected if I start to drag but change my mind and
2. This means I cannot stop multiple items dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound to me like you should be using the grids default selection model with a the ux 'checkcolumn' that is provided with the extjs library.  This would let you be able to select rows for reorder independent of a checkbox selection of the row.